Visual swatch render as low resolution
I have an issue with my product visual swatch.
When my product has a swatch image, it works fine.

but if my product did not have swatch picture.
I set the attribute properties to Use Product Image for Swatch if Possible.
it render in small resolution,so when it show in front page it will get expand to be blurr image

I already try adding  tag inside view.xml files
<media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
             <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
                 <width>50</width>
                 <height>50</height>
             </image>
        </images>
</media>

The image with the swatch image renders at 50x50 pixels. However, if there is no swatch image, it renders at 15x20 pixels.
Am I using the wrong <image id>?
